# Insert variable values into a string

Tags: python

I want to introduce a variable `[i]` into a string in Python.

For example look at the following script. I just want to be able to give a name to the image, for example `geo[0].tif` ... to `geo[i].tif`, or if you use an accountant as I can replace a portion of the value chain to generate a counter.

```
data = self.cmd("r.out.gdal in=rdata out=geo.tif")
self.dataOutTIF.setValue("geo.tif")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
data = self.cmd("r.out.gdal in=rdata out=geo{0}.tif".format(i))
self.dataOutTIF.setValue("geo{0}.tif".format(i))
```

> ```
> str.format(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this
>   method is called can contain literal
>   text or replacement fields delimited
>   by braces {}. Each replacement field
>   contains either the numeric index of a
>   positional argument, or the name of a
>   keyword argument. Returns a copy of
>   the string where each replacement
>   field is replaced with the string
>   value of the corresponding argument.
>
> ```
> >>> "The sum of 1 + 2 is {0}".format(1+2)
> 'The sum of 1 + 2 is 3'
> ```
>
> See Format String Syntax for a description of the various formatting
>   options that can be specified in
>   format strings.
>
> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3.0, and
>   should be preferred to the %
>   formatting described in String
>   Formatting Operations in new code.
>
> ```
> New in version 2.6.
> ```

Comment: These days is `.format` considered more pythonic than my solution?

Comment: Yes, it is officially endorsed, and your solution is not, iirc. No blame attaches :)

Comment: @orangeoctopus, Only for Python2.6+ http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 21):

You can use the operator `%` to inject strings into strings:

```
"first string is: %s, second one is: %s" % (str1, "geo.tif")
```

This will give:

```
"first string is: STR1CONTENTS, second one is geo.tif"
```

You could also do integers with `%d`:

```
"geo%d.tif" % 3   # geo3.tif
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python 3, then you can use F-string. Here is an example

```
 record_variable = 'records'    
 print(f"The element '{record_variable}' is found in the received data")
```

in this case, the output will be like:

```
The element 'records' is found in the received data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 3.6+, the best solution is using f-strings:

```
data = self.cmd(f"r.out.gdal in=rdata out=geo{i}.tif")
self.dataOutTIF.setValue(f"geo{i}.tif")
```

It is the more readable and performant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var = input("Input the variable")
print("Your variable is " + var)
```

---

Note that `var` must be a string, if it isn't, convert it to a string with `var = str(var)`.

For example

```
var = 5  # This is an integer, not a string
print("Var is " + str(var))
```

This solution is the easiest to read/understand, so better for beginners, as it is just simple string concatenation.

Answer (score -4):

You can also do this:

```
name = input("what is your name?")
print("this is",+name)
```

Comment: Actually, this does not work.. did you mean `print("this is " + name)`?