# How Do I Display My User Input as My Graph Title (Python)

Tags: python, graph, title

this is the code for asking user to input their datetime:

```
startTime = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter start time in format like 21/7/2014 0:00 :'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
endTime   = datetime.strptime(raw_input('please enter end time in format like 22/7/2014 23:57 :') , '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

how do i display the user input as my graph title along side with other info

this is my graph title code:

```
plt.title('Max Value: {:.2f} at {}, Mode: {:.2f}, Average: {:.2f})'.format(max(y), t[np.argmax(y)], mode(y)[0][0], np.average(y)))
```

i tried this but it didn't work:

```
 plt.title('Irradiance vs Time Graph at startTime to endTime \n Max Value: {:.2f} at {}, Mode: {:.2f}, Average: {:.2f})'startTime, endTime, .format(max(y), t[np.argmax(y)], mode(y)[0][0], np.average(y)))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This comes down to putting variables into strings.  Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367288/insert-variable-values-into-a-string-in-python. If you convert your variables to strings in advance, then you can just use `+` to connect a bunch of strings together.

Comment: String formatting using `.format()` is much more idiomatic and more pythonic than using string concatenation. Not to mention easier to use and less error prone.

Comment: It makes no sense to ask the question like this, because **the previously tried code already shows how to do it**. The way to insert `startTime` and `endTime` into the string is **the same way** that `max(y)`, `t[np.argmax(y)]`, etc. were **already being** inserted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proper way to do string formatting by using the `.format()` method is like this:

`'My name is {}'.format('Ian')`

which will output `'My name is Ian'`. To use it in your case:

```
long_title = 'Irradiance vs Time Graph at {} to {} \n Max Value: {:.2f} at {}, Mode: {:.2f}, Average: {:.2f})'

plt.title(long_title.format(
                            startTime,
                            endTime,
                            max(y),
                            t[np.argmax(y)],
                            mode(y)[0][0],
                            np.average(y)
))
```